# Multiple references in git repository

Tags: c++, git

I have 3 repositories:

- Application
- Lib1
- Lib2

Application needs both Lib1 and Lib2 to run. Lib1 requires Lib2 for compilation and referencing.
I recently added Lib 2 as a submodule to Lib 1 and after that I added Lib1 **and** Lib2 as submodules to the Application repository. Like so:

```
-Application
|-submodule Lib1
| |-submodule Lib2
|-submodule Lib2
```

Now my Problem/Question:
Lib2 is duplicated in the Application repository. Was adding the submodule Lib2 to both Lib1 and Application the right choice if i want to use the two libraries elsewhere (other projects/repositories)? Or is it better to only include the libraries in the compiler as additional include folder and let developers get or checkout their repositories on their own?

Comment: Having Lib2 included twice is definitely not the right solution: each copy could have a different version of Lib2! However, you need to provide more information if you want someone to say what you _should_ do.

Comment: What information exactly do you need?

Comment: Do you need to develop Lib1 in isolation from App, or will it (and Lib2) always be used as part of App or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple dependencies, the best practice is to list them all on *one* level.

So Application would have Lib1 and Lib2 as a dependency.
The fact that Lib1 has a dependency to Lib2 can be use to check that App refers to the same Lib2 than Lib1 does.

But the idea remains to:

- initialize (ie checkout, as in `git submodule update --init`) only submodules within App (so no `--recursive` here)
- Make sure `Lib1` builds with `App/lib2`, not `./Lib2`.